# port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have used my EC2 for over 7 months. Suddenly decided to not work anymore. I cannot ssh into it although I used the exact same ssh script as I used before.

> ssh: connect to host XXXXXX.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out

I restarted the instance.
The status checks says ok.
[image]

I also verified inbound security group on port 22:

[image]

Comment: Is the public IP address still the same, and thus also the public DNS? If you turned the server off and on again the public IP would change if you didn't use an Elastic IP address.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about that

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have configured it on **security group for port 22**, you can refer it from the following link:    http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html